# Modify adsense search code

Tags: adsense

I'm using AdSense Custom Search Engine and want search results to be opened in new tab but the code doesn't pass XHTML Strict DTD I'm using. I'm wondering if they'll penalize me if I select in AdSense UI 'new window' and then delete target="_blank" from:

```
<form action="http://www.google.hr" id="cse-search-box" target="_blank">
```

then put JavaScript in next line do the job:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("cse-search-box").setAttribute("target","_blank");</script>
```

They allow to change code only for W3C specifications, but they described only properly closing tags in support and emphasize “be sure to modify the search code only as described”.

Transitional DTD allow target="_blank", but that's not an option.

Does anyone has this kind of experience?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone will need this information: no, Google will not penalize you if you do something like this.

I did it one month ago to see what'll happen. And nothing happened :) 
Didn't get any warning, ads are still where they was - it seams that's ok with them.